# How can the shape in this picture be descibed mathematically?

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I'm reading an [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statphys-Boltzmann/#1.1) on Boltzmann that contains the following figure:
[image]

It is obviously related to harmonic oscillators (since the article says so), but how could I describe this figure mathematically? I've seen it somewhere before, but have no recollection of where.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lissajous figure with $x = \sin (4 t)$ and $y = \sin (7 t)$.

Count the number of extrema along the top and along the side to get the ratio of frequencies.

[image]

Comment: Just get out your oscilloscope and a couple of sine wave generators. (From my high school physics lab)